# Return unknown characters in DateFormat as literals

Tags: java, android, date, date-format

Designing an Android app that requires users to be able to enter a custom date format which is then used to display the current time/date in the exact user requested format with DateFormat.

I need users to be able to mix literals (i.e. actual characters that are not parsed) together with the characters they are using to format the date.
I understand that you can simply surround the literals in ' (single quotes) but my desired behavior is: any characters that can be formatted as a date part are and any other characters should just return the original character.

For example: if I try to format the date with the string `T hh:mm`, I get the error: `Unknown pattern character 'T'`. (As a fallback I return the original string). My desired behavior is to return the formatted date with the Unknown character e.g. `T 11:03`

How can I achieve this?

To clarify:  I don't want to rely on single-quotes for two reasons:
 1. I want to make it simpler for the user to enter a date format and
 2. I want it to still work even if the user enters an incorrect format

(As an aside I know that when setting the format for a `TextClock` view the behavior is as desired: unknown characters are simply returned literally)

Comment: Your question is unclear. You said you already know the answer is to surround your literal with a pair of single-quote (APOSTROPHE, Unicode decimal 39) characters. That is the correct solution. Yet you chose to omit the quote marks; why?

Comment: I am giving the user the option to enter his own format. I therefore don't want to rely on single-quotes for two reasons: 1) I want to make it simpler for the user to enter a date format and 2) I want it to still work even if the user enters an incorrect format

Comment: Better to edit the Question with those clarifications than to post as comments. The comment is well-stated and more specific. I suggest adding that as a pair of bullets to the text of the Question.